# How to toggle IGC track visibility in OpenLayers based on HTML checkbox On/Off status?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I need to be able to toggle ON/OFF the visibility of IGC tracks. For example, In the code below I have checkboxes that I want to control the visibility of the track on the map.

[image]

I am following the example from https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/igc.html

However, my application may have up to 120 ICG files, which I need to be able to control On/Off or it will be completely useless.

My test application is here:

https://f0n.github.io/IGC/

But essentially, I have the checkbox defined

```
<input type="checkbox" name="pilot1" value="Kalir">Kalir<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pilot2" value="Mentler">Mentler<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pilot3" value="Irlbeck">Irlbeck<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pilot4" value="Caylor">Caylor<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pilot5" value="Kolynich">Kolynich<br>
```

And in the OpenLayers script

```
var igcUrls = [
'Kalir.igc',
'Mentler.igc',
'Irlbeck.igc',
'Caylor.igc',
'Kolynich.igc'
];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the id of your check boxes to the property you want to filter (e.g. PLT) you could do the filtering in the style function:

```
var styleFunction = function(feature) {
  if (document.getElementById(feature.get('PLT')).checked) {
    var color = colors[feature.get('PLT')];
    var style = styleCache[color];
    if (!style) {
      style = new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: color,
          width: 3
        })
      });
      styleCache[color] = style;
    }
    return style;
  } else {
    return [];
  }
};
```